# Hyperledger fabric 1.4 chaincode instantiate constenser error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using Hyperledger fabric 1.4  with raft as ordering service. whenever I tried to instantiate the chaincode, the command get stucked and after waiting so long there is no output.
I am getting the warning like rejecting the delivering request for- because of **constenser** **error**.

please help me to fix this out.

[below here image is attached that depict the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUiic.jpg)

[Logs orderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcPu3.jpg)

Comment: There are couple of reasons for consenter error

1. whenever the leader selection process is going on then it won't accept any txn because the leader is not present. so check whether the leader is completed or not before sending the the txn. try `docker logs orderer_node 2>&1 | grep leader`

2. check the connection between the raft node

Comment: In your orderer logs (image), fix the `Warning` by usinf correct variable for logging. Are you sure that you are using `fabric:1.4.X` version. If possible share your all the files.

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable time to help me. Currently all orderers are running on local  system and  I am sharing the source code url here. https://bitbucket.org/mayank017/hyperledger_scrach/src/etcd_raft/

Comment: please share the complete orderer logs.